# php: how to fetch multiple tables in mysqli

Tags: php

we have two table for example `persons1` and `persons2` and out put should be rows of those tables
for exemple:

```
`persons1`
+----+-------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | john        |
|  2 | Sophia      |
+----+-------------+

and

`persons2`
+----+-------------+
| id | the_name    |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Olivia      |
|  2 | Jackson     |
+----+-------------+
```

Output is :

```
array(
[1,'john'],
[2,'Sophia'],
[1,'Olivia'],
[2,'Jackson'],
)
```

thank you

Comment: You can use the UNION statement to combine the results of two separate queries (as long as they have the same column count and data types)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union` like this:

```
SELECT id, name as `the_name` FROM `persons1`
UNION
SELECT id, the_name FROM `persons2`;
```

which outputs:

```
| id | the_name |
|----| ---------|
|  1 |     John |
|  2 |   Sophia |
|  1 |   Olivia |
|  2 |  Jackson |
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a90165/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.name AS `the_name` FROM persons1 p1
UNION
SELECT p2.id, p2.the_name FROM persons2 p2;
```